# com.google.firebase.iid.zzf cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.iid.zzi

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

1. use the library: react-native-push-notification, version 3.1.1
2. the app crash when the android receive a remote notification, but it's no problem in the ios
3. all the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.iid.zzf cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.iid.zzi
>           at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzk.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source:4)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1658)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1687)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)

4. build.gradle

> googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
>
> Blockquote
>
> firebaseVersion ="+"
>
> compileSdkVersion = 27
>
> buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
>
> targetSdkVersion = 27
>
> supportLibVersion = "27.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Just use dependencies  compatable with 27.0.3 replace firebaseVersion and googlePlayServicesVersion  ="+" with dependecies version.

Comment: i am not sure witch version is compatable, but i try it with the googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" // default: "x" , firebaseVersion ="17.3.2". the error is there also. but i find the simulator will work. the crash just occured in the real android device. i used samsung S7